# RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol returns CurrencyEnglishName instead

Tags: c#, currency, regioninfo

I'm trying to convert ISO currency codes into currency symbols, but the return values for `RegionInfo` seem to be swapped. Here is my code:

```
foreach (CultureInfo nfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
     RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(nfo.LCID);
     Log("ISO: " + region.ISOCurrencySymbol);
     Log("Symbol: " + region.CurrencySymbol);
}
```

Edit: The Log()-method just prints a string for debug purposes.

For each language I get something like:

- ISO: US Dollar (should be "USD")
- Symbol: USD (should be "$")

How could this have happened and how could I fix it?

Edit2: Tested some more: Most fields in RegionInfo seem to be empty, .CurrencyNativeName throws a NotImplementedException. What the heck is going on here?

Comment: What does the `Log` function do?

Comment: Thats just a debug log

Comment: It prints `USD` and `$` in my machine. Are you sure about that? What is your environments? (.NET Framework version or something..)

Comment: Obviously something is very wrong on my end, but I have no idea what that could be. Repaired and reinstalled .Net-Framework but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but here works for me

```
        public List<string> getCurrencyCode()
        {
            List<string> CountryList = new List<string>();
            List<string> CurrencyList = new List<string>();
            CultureInfo[] getCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

            foreach (CultureInfo getCulture in getCultureInfo)
            {
                 RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(getCulture.LCID);
                //Region includes country name and currency symbols
                //make sure no repeats
                if (!(CountryList.Contains(ri.EnglishName))) 
                {
                   CountryList.Add(ri.EnglishName);
                   CurrencyList.Add(ri.ISOCurrencySymbol);                    
                }
           }
            return CurrencyList;
        }
```